# What's the kubectl equivalent of docker exec bash in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I successfully deployed my Kubernetes app using `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`.
When I try to hit the URL endpoint, I'm getting an `nginx 404 Not Found` error page.

My next step is to open a `bash` shell on the docker instance that is running my app.  How do I do this in Kubernetes?

**How do I ssh into the docker container running my app, or docker exec bash to an app I've deployed to Kubernetes?**

If I were running in docker I would run `docker ps` to find the container ID and then run `docker exec -t ### bash` to open a shell on my container to look around to troubleshoot why something isn't working.

**What is the equivalent way to do this in Kubernetes?**

### Searching for a solution

I searched and found [this URL](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/), which says how to get a shell on your app.
The summary of that URL is:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/shell-demo.yaml
kubectl get pod shell-demo
kubectl exec --stdin --tty shell-demo -- /bin/bash
```

But when I tried the equivalent commands, I got an error see below:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace my-app-namespace
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb         1/1     Running   0           2h
```

Then I tried:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty my-app-namespace -- /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "my-app-namespace" not found
exit status 1
```

I figured this happened because I was trying to exec into the namespace not the pod, so I also tried with the `dpl-my-app-...` (see below)  but got the same error.

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb -- /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb" not found
exit status 1
```

What is the command I need to get the pod instance so that `kubectl exec` will work?

Comment: Your `kubectl get pods` command has a `--namespace` option; you need to repeat this in the `kubectl exec` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As correctly stated by @David Maze:

> Your `kubectl get pods` command has a `--namespace` option; you need to repeat this in the `kubectl exec` command. – David Maze 12 hours ago

If you've created your `Deployment`: `dpl-my-app` in a namespace: `my-app-namespace` you should also specify the `--namespace`/`-n` parameter in all of your commands.

> A side note!
>
> There is a tool to change namespaces, called: [kubens](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/kubens)

---

With a following command:

- `kubectl exec --stdin --tty my-app-namespace -- /bin/bash`

You've correctly identified the issue that you are trying to exec into a `namespace` but not into a `Pod`

With a following command:

- `kubectl exec --stdin --tty dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb -- /bin/bash`

You've tried to exec into a **`Pod`** named `dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb` but in a `default` namespace. Not in a `namespace` your `Pod` is residing.

To exec into your `Pod` in a specific `namespace` you should use following command:

- `kubectl exec --stdin --tty --namespace my-app-namespace dpl-my-app-787bc5b7d-4ftkb -- /bin/bash`

Please notice the `--namespace` is before `--` where the commands to the `Pod` should be placed (like `-- /bin/bash`).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Overview: Working with objects: Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Debug application cluster: Get shell running container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)*